# How to display image in a listview with lrucache?

Tags: android, image, file, explorer, lru

I'm a beginner at Android development. I want to display the images in small size from sd card. Because of large image that is to slow, so I need to use a `LruCache`, but it doesn't work.  I'm also using SwipeView. [Here](http://www.androiddevelopersolution.com/2013/12/android-file-or-folder-listing-from-sd.html) is a FileExplorer example.

This is my `ListFragment`:

```
public class Windows extends ListFragment {

    private File currentDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Pictures/pic/");
    private FileArrayAdapter adapter;
    int fragNum;

    private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;

    static Windows init(int val) {
        Windows List = new Windows();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("val", val);
        List.setArguments(args);

        return List;
    }

    public class FileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Albumb> {

        private Context c;
        private int id;
        private List<Albumb> items;


        public FileArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Albumb> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            c = context;
            id = textViewResourceId;
            items = objects;
        }

        public Albumb getItem(int i) {
            return items.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(id, null);
            }

            final Albumb item = items.get(position);
            if (item != null) {
                TextView t1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                TextView t2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
                TextView t3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextViewDate);

                ImageView imageCity = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.fd_Icon1);

                String type = item.getImage();
                if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("directory_icon")) {
                    String uri = "drawable/" + item.getImage();
                    int imageResource = c.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, c.getPackageName());
                    Drawable image = c.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
                    imageCity.setImageDrawable(image);

                } else {
                    final String imageKey = item.getName();
                    final Bitmap bm = getBitmapFromMemCache(currentDir + imageKey);

                    if (bm == null) {
                        BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageCity);
                        task.execute(imageKey);
                    }
                }

                if (t1 != null)
                    t1.setText(item.getName());
                if (t2 != null)
                    t2.setText(item.getData());
                if (t3 != null)
                    t3.setText(item.getDate());

            }

            return v;
        }

        public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

            Bitmap bm = null;

            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

            return bm;
        }

        public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
            final int height = options.outHeight;
            final int width = options.outWidth;
            int inSampleSize = 1;

            if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
                if (width > height) {
                    inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
                } else {
                    inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
                }
            }

            return inSampleSize;
        }

        class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

            private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

            public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
                imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
            }

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

                final Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(params[0], 80, 80);
                addBitmapToMemoryCache(params[0], bitmap);
                return bitmap;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
                    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageViewReference.get();
                    if (imageView != null) {
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fragNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("val") : 1;


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.windows_frag,
                container, false);


        final int memClass
                = ((ActivityManager) layoutView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE))
                .getMemoryClass();

        // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
        final int cacheSize = 1024 * 1024 * memClass / 8;


        mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {

            @Override
            protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
                // The cache size will be measured in bytes rather than number of items.
                return bitmap.getByteCount();
            }
        };


        fill(currentDir);

        return layoutView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    private void fill(File f) {
        File[] dirs = f.listFiles();

        List<Albumb> dir = new ArrayList<Albumb>();
        List<Albumb> fls = new ArrayList<Albumb>();
        try {
            for (File ff : dirs) {
                String name = ff.getName();
                Date lastModDate = new Date(ff.lastModified());
                DateFormat formater = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
                String date_modify = formater.format(lastModDate);
            /*
             * Note: Remove this
             * name.equalsIgnoreCase("Personal" if u
             * want to list all ur sd card file and folder
             */
                if (ff.isDirectory()) {

                    File[] fbuf = ff.listFiles();
                    int buf = 0;
                    if (fbuf != null) {
                        buf = fbuf.length;
                    } else
                        buf = 0;
                    String num_item = String.valueOf(buf);
                    if (buf == 0)
                        num_item = num_item + " item";
                    else
                        num_item = num_item + " items";

                    // String formated = lastModDate.toString();
                    dir.add(new Albumb(ff.getName(), num_item, date_modify, ff
                            .getAbsolutePath(), "directory_icon"));
                } else {
                /*
                 * Note: Remove this
                 * f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Personal"
                 * if u want to list all ur sd card file and folder
                 */

                    fls.add(new Albumb(ff.getName(), ff.length() / 1024 + " KByte",
                            date_modify, ff.getAbsolutePath(), "file_icon"));

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        Collections.sort(dir);
        Collections.sort(fls);
        dir.addAll(fls);
        if (!f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getName() + "/Pictures/pic"))
            dir.add(0, new Albumb("..", "Parent Directory", "", f.getParent(),
                    "directory_up"));
        adapter = new FileArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.file_view, dir);
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    }


    public void addBitmapToMemoryCache(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (getBitmapFromMemCache(key) == null) {
            mMemoryCache.put(key, bitmap);
        }
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(String key) {
        return (Bitmap) mMemoryCache.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Albumb o = adapter.getItem(position);
        if (o.getImage().equalsIgnoreCase("directory_icon")
                || o.getImage().equalsIgnoreCase("directory_up")) {
            currentDir = new File(o.getPath());
            fill(currentDir);
        }

    }
}
```

And this is my view model for the `ArrayAdapter`:

```
public class Albumb implements Comparable<Albumb> {
    private String name;
    private String data;
    private String date;
    private String path;
    private String image;

    public Albumb(String name, String date, String dt, String path, String image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.data = date;
        this.path = path;
        this.image = image;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public int compareTo(Albumb o) {
        if (this.name != null)
            return this.name.toLowerCase().compareTo(o.getName().toLowerCase());
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
05-01 23:43:08.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12687): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
05-01 23:43:08.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12687): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-01 23:43:08.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12687):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
05-01 23:43:08.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12687):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
05-01 23:43:08.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12687):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
05-01 23:43:08.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12687):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
05-01 23:43:08.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12687):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-01 23:43:08.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12687):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-01 23:43:08.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12687):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
05-01 23:43:08.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12687):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
05-01 23:43:08.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12687):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-01 23:43:08.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12687): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: key == null || value == null
05-01 23:43:08.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12687):    at android.support.v4.util.LruCache.put(LruCache.java:117)
05-01 23:43:08.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12687):    at com.example.swipetab.Windows.addBitmapToMemoryCache(Windows.java:349)
05-01 23:43:08.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12687):    at com.example.swipetab.Windows$FileArrayAdapter$BitmapWorkerTask.doInBackground(Windows.java:216)
05-01 23:43:08.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12687):    at com.example.swipetab.Windows$FileArrayAdapter$BitmapWorkerTask.doInBackground(Windows.java:1)
05-01 23:43:08.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12687):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-01 23:43:08.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12687):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When putting an item inside the LruCache, both the key and value must be non-null.

```
public final V put(K key, V value) {
    if (key == null || value == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("key == null || value == null");
    }
    ...
```

Most likely decodeSampledBitmapFromUri() is returning null in some cases.

Comment: I checked it, and the key is null, but I don't know why.

Comment: Are you sure? From the exception call stack, it would seem the value is null, not they key. If the key was null, the call to getBitmapFromMemCache(key) would've crashed first, since get() doesn't accept a null key either.